# Python won't pops up message box even after passing commands

Tags: python, events, tkcalendar

I am in the middle of the application ; however, am stucked at the moment.

I have Used below widget to select/display the date so that the user can select the date accordingly.

```
self.Entry_Date = DateEntry(root, AdvisorDetails, width = 10, background='darkblue',foreground='white', borderwidth=1, command = self.checks_WeekStartDate)
self.Entry_Date.grid(row=2, column=10, pady=5, padx=5)
```

It allow users to select the date. My aim is to pop up a message box if selected date is not 'Monday' saying "error, selected date must be Week Commencing date"
For that I have created a function below which will check the selected date and then pop-ups the message accordingly ; however, there is no message box even if the user don't select "Monday"(week commencing date)

## function below

```
def checks_WeekStartDate(self):
    self.Selected_Date = self.Entry_Date.get_date().strftime("%A")
    if self.Selected_Date != "Monday":
        messagebox.Message("Selection Error", "Please select Week Commecing date as 'Monday' Only")
    else:
        return self.Selected_Date.strftime("%A")
```

Please help

[image: Main GUI]

[image: Date Picker]

Comment: I'm not sure a `tkcalendar.DateEntry` has a command option...

Comment: Thanks, is there any other workaround ?

Comment: @AnkurKhera ***"any other"***: Follow the documentation [Virtual Events](https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/DateEntry.html#virtual-events)

Comment: @ stovfl
Thanks for your update, I am able to fix this...

Answer (score 1):

```
self.Entry_Date = DateEntry(Frame_AdvisorDetails, width = 10, background='darkblue',foreground='white', borderwidth=1)
        self.Entry_Date.grid(row=2, column=10, pady=5, padx=5)
        self.Entry_Date.bind("<<DateEntrySelected>>", self.checks_WeekStartDate)

   def checks_WeekStartDate(self, events):
        self.Selected_Date = self.Entry_Date.get_date()
        self.Selected_Date = self.Selected_Date.strftime("%A")
        if self.Selected_Date == "Monday":
            print("You selected Monday")
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Please select Week Commecing date as Monday")
```